# How to get the first letter of a full name string using loop?

Tags: java

Write an application that prompts a user for a full name and street address and construct an ID from the user’s initials and numeric part of the address. For example, the user William Henry Harrison who lives at 34 Elm would have an ID of WHH34, whereas user Addison Mitchell who lived at 1778 Monroe would have an ID of AM1778. Save the file as ConstructID.java.

this is what have so far, w/c my teacher says its wrong...

```
import java.util.*;
public class ConstructID {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String name1, address1, address2;

        Scanner kevs = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter your fullname. Encluding Middle Initial, Separated by spaces.");

        name1 = kevs.next();
        name2 = kevs.next();
        name3 = kevs.next();

        name1 = name1.toUpperCase();
        name2 = name2.toUpperCase();
        name3 = name3.toUpperCase();

        name1 = name1.substring(0,1);
        name2 = name2.substring(0,1);
        name3 = name3.substring(0,1);

        System.out.println("\nEnter your address. Separated by spaces.");

        address1 = kevs.next();
        address2 = kevs.nextLine();


        do {

            if (address1 == address1.substring(0,1) || address1 == address1.substring(0,2) || address1 == address1.substring(0,3) || address1 == address1.substring(0,4) || address1 == address1.substring(0,5) || address1 == address1.substring(0,6))
            System.out.println("\nYour ID: " + name1 + name2 + name3 + address1);

        } while (address1 == address2);
    }
}
```

NOTE: *I can't use array* :( The topic of this question is all about loop and string.. no array.. so please help.. :((

Comment: Did you try running your code and check if it works as you expect ?

Comment: What exactly is that `if` statement supposed to be doing? If you write out your logic in English, it may make it more sense to you (and us) what the code should look like.

Comment: 1) *"my teacher says its wrong"*  What is wrong with it? 2) *"I CAN'T USE ARRAY"*  Don't SHOUT at us!  It is not our fault.

Comment: sorry.. :((

Jonathon: i think my teacher want's me to make a loop out of the name1,name2,name... I just can't get the right code.. ;( please help..

Andrew: Im sorry sir.. I'm just to desperate to get this program.. sorry...

Comment: @GladwynRomines: don't apologize -- instead explain your problems and tell the details. Your post and question is very vague. Please tell us exactly what is wrong, what isn't working.

Comment: thanks sir.. my problem is this... i need to make a single string for the FULLNAME... so i need to loop..maybe using for loop... so that the first input that the program ask's will now be 1 string... and get the first letter of each part of the fullname which is for example "gladwyn leo romines" so the program will get the first letter of each part w/c is 'g' 'l' and 'r' and make is uppercase...

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: sir.. i hope u can help.. thanks

Comment: @GladwynRomines: you're posting your assignment, not what is wrong with your code attempt. Again you may wish to clarify 1) what is wrong with your attempt, and 2) what exactly you don't understand.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: sir.. i just dont know that much how to get the right codes to loop and make that 3 strings in the fullname in just 1 string.. and get every first letter.. ;(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        String name, address;

        Scanner kevs = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter your fullname. Including Middle Initial, Separated by spaces.");

        //get the full name
        name = kevs.nextLine();

        System.out.println("\nEnter your address. Separated by spaces.");
        //get the address
        address = kevs.nextLine();

        String initials = "";
        //get the first letter of the name and add it to our initial string
        char c = name.charAt(0);
        initials += c;
        for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++) {
            char letter = name.charAt(i);
            // if we find a space, select the first letter after it until the end
            if (letter == ' ') {
                initials += name.charAt(i + 1);
            }

        }
        String addressNum = "";
        //this bool is so that we only select characters up to the first space
        boolean finished = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < address.length(); i++) {
            if (!finished) {
                char num = address.charAt(i);
                if (num != ' ') {
                    //add characters to the address string until there is a space
                    addressNum += num;
                } else // we found the first space so we are now finished
                {
                    finished = true;
                }
            } else //we are finished so leave the loop
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        //concatenate the strings
        System.out.println(initials + addressNum);

    }
```

Comment: I mean if you could explain the downvotes that would be awesome, this code works....

Comment: sir... thank you! 1 thing missing though...the output letters are not in uppercase.. but thanks! :) i think i can handle it from here.. Godbless!

Comment: That's pretty good explanation on a forum that is meant to help others.

Comment: i got it sir..thank you again.. :) its working flawlessly.. Godbless

Comment: @pravat this is not a forum, is a Q/A site. Also, for this kind of questions, you should check [What is an acceptable answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118694/182862), section 10, and [How to ask and answer homework questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10811/182862)

Comment: @MorningDew Would you consider adding some narrative to explain why this code works, and what makes it an answer to the question? This would be very helpful to the person asking the question, and anyone else who comes along.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use an array, use a list.  Look at the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) for `java.util.List` to understand what a list can do.  (Or you lecture notes!)

I expect that reason that your teacher has said that what you have written is wrong is that it *assumes* that *everyone's* name consists of a first name, a middle name and a last name.  I'm sure that you know that this is not correct.  Some people have many middle names, or none at all.  Indeed, some people have only one name.

What your teacher wants is code that will cope with an *arbitrary* number of names.  An array would be a bad choice for that ... because you would need to predict how big to make the array *before* you read the names from the user.

Comment: true :( can u please help me how to make the the full name just 1 string and loop it in order to get the first letter of each part of the name? :(

Comment: I'm not going to write your code for you.  You will learn most by actually writing it yourself ... from scratch.  Reading someone else's code won't teach you how to write your own.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String name1, address1;

    Scanner kevs = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter your fullname. Encluding Middle Initial, Separated by spaces.\n");
    name1 = kevs.nextLine();
    name1 = name1.toUpperCase();
    StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(name1);
    String name = "";
    while(tokens.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String value= tokens.nextToken();
        name += value.substring(0,1);
    }
    System.out.println("\nEnter your  full address. Separated by spaces.\n");
    address1 = kevs.nextLine();
    address1 = address1.toUpperCase();
    StringTokenizer tokens2 = new StringTokenizer(address1);
    Integer numericAddress = null;
    while(tokens2.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String value1= tokens2.nextToken();
        try {
            numericAddress = Integer.valueOf(value1);
        }catch(NumberFormatException ne) {
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }

    String output = name+numericAddress.toString();

    System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: i cant still learn if i wont understand all the codes mr. pravat gave.. now its my part to understand all the codes above... i still can learn.. a lot more easier now.. :) thanks!

Comment: @GladwynRomines by experience, you learn more when you do the things instead of checking how others did. A technique for this is trial and error: try something, test it, check results, if is not the desired result try again. By doing this, at least you will know the most important thing that nor this or accepted answer can't address: **understand what you're doing** (good or wrong).